# Вывести список файлов в папке на С\С++

Tags: c, файлы, c++

Можно ли средствами стандартной библиотеки получить список файлов в папке? Использование WinAPI не подойдет, т.к. нужна кроссплатформенность на уровне исходников.
Либо какие есть сторонние кроссплатформенные библиоткеки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно тут посмотреть: [Как получить в C++ список всех файлов из текущего каталога (в Windows, UNIX, MS-DOS)](http://iphone-sdk-programming.blogspot.ru/2010/05/c-windows-unix-ms-dos.html). Хороший кроссплатформенный пример.

Comment: инклуды пропущены или мне кажется?

Comment: Увы не кажется, но думаю их не сложно будет подобрать по используемым функциям.

Comment: просто посмотрите код страницы и увидите какие там заголовки.       
просто браузер воспринимает название файла в угловых скобках как одну из команд HTML и не показывает её.

Comment: Что бы вам было проще выписал заголовки...     
1) windows.h    
2) sys/types.h dirent.h    
3) dir.h

Comment: Там есть ссылка на оригинал. В оригинале все инклуды прописаны.

Answer (score 4):

Для кроссплатформенного доступа к файловой системе используйте boost.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html